# How to extract all the rodata data and bss section using IDC script in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, disassembly, ida-plugin, idapython

test Platform is 
32 bit Linux ELF and 32 bit Windows PE.

I use IDC script to extract all the functions from binary and dump 
into a file, then do the analysis based on the examples in IDA Pro book.

But I don't know how to extract .data .rodata and .bss
sections from ELF file using IDC script.

Currently I use IDA Pro to create a asm file, and use Python script to 
do the string parser work, extracting .data .rodata and .bss
sections from this asm file.

Basically It works fine, but a really tedious modification work is required, 
and as my test base is relatively large(notepad++ and others..), I have to
spend lots of time do modify work to correctly extract this three sections.

My question is "is there any idc script/idapython script can extract .data .rodata and .bss
sections from ELF file?" and any solutions on Windows are also welcomed.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by extract section ? What information exactly do you want to get from there ?

Comment: @ws Just the data info defined in .data .rodata and .bss sections...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `.bss` section something like the following may work for you:

```
import idaapi
import idc

print "section .bss"
start = idaapi.get_segm_by_name(".bss").startEA
end = idaapi.get_segm_by_name(".bss").endEA
item = idc.NextHead(start - 1, end)
while item != BADADDR:
   next = idc.NextHead(item, end)
   if next != BADADDR:
      print "%s: resb %d" % (idc.Name(item), next - item)
   else:
      print "%s: resb %d" % (idc.Name(item), end - item)
   item = next
```

although in practice, `NextHead` does not seem to pick up anything named as `unk_XXXX`, so you may need to further iterate over the section to determine whether there are any cross references to an address to decide whether to associate a declaration with it.

For the `.data` and `.rodata` sections you will need to change to `db/dw/dd/...` as appropriate and additionally dump the content of the related items. The challenge for items in these sections is to properly determine the size of each item and correctly choose `db/dw/dd/...` Dumping raw bytes with `db` may be the simplest approach here.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Use carefully, I didn't check this code
#beware errors
#It's IDAPython, not IDC
#

import idautils
import idc
import idaapi

segfiles = {".rodata": "rodata.bin",
            ".data": "data.bin"}

# over all segments
for s in idautils.Segments():
    if idc.SegName(s) in segfiles:
        #if we need this segment ...
        fname = segfiles[idc.SegName(s)]
        f = open(fname, "wb")
        start = idc.GetSegmentAttr(s, idc.SEGATTR_START)
        end = idc.GetSegmentAttr(s, idc.SEGATTR_END)
        #from start to end write all to file
        while start < end:
            b = idc.Byte(start)
            f.write(b)
            start += 1
        f.close()
```

Comment: Hi ws, Thank you a lot for your answer! what I am trying to do is to generate file like this:[bss](https://gist.github.com/computereasy/2ce8cf016802a17970e5)   Is it possible to use IDA script to generate this from binary?

Comment: Run IDA from command line with -S switch